# Slide and fade jquery

Tags: jquery

How can i slide a div in whilst it fades in using jquery.  I guess it would need to be offset slightly from the position stipulated within the style sheet.

So for example this div would slide in from the left whilst fading into 100% from 0.

```
<div id="pageintro">We are a wholly independent</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the element is already hidden / opacity at 0:

```
$('#pageintro').animate({
    opacity: 1,
    left: '+=100'
}, 1000);
```

The above example will only work on elements with the 'left:'  css attribute defined :)

Alternatively:

```
$('#pageintro').animate({
    opacity: 1,
    marginLeft: '+=100'
}, 1000);
```

This will work on most elements :)

They will move the element 100px from the left to the right and from 0 opacity to 1 (completely visible) in 1 second.

:)

Comment: it works the fade but it doesnt move from left to right... :0)

Comment: try "marginLeft: '+=100'" instead. :)

left will only work with position:relative and when the css left attribute is defined :)

Comment: As long as pageIntro's position is not static (which is set by default) then Damien's solution should work. In your css, try setting pageIntro to have a relative or static position.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer an old post, but jQuery Mobile 1.1RC1 performs this by default[1]

[1] http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/pages/page-transitions.html